# Focus does not change from EditText to TextBox in WebView android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `EditText` on top of a `WebView`, for search. After search, user gets some `TextBox` rendered through a link coming from server. Cursor blinks in both `EditText`and in the `TextBox` of the `WebView`. But even when I try to type something in the `TextBox` of the `WebView`, letters gets on to the `EditText` but not in the `TextBox` of the `WebView`.

Any idea on why this problem is happening in the emulator.

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/white"
 android:tileMode="repeat" >

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


   <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
      android:focusable="true" 
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true">  

      <EditText android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      </EditText>
      <Button android:text="Search" 
        android:id="@+id/searchCatalogButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </Button>

  </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/browserwebview"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="75dip"
      android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="@drawable/black"
        android:tileMode="repeat">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/buttonBackCatalog"
        android:src="@drawable/greenarrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/black"
        android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/black"
    android:tileMode="repeat">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footerLayoutHome"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/footerMainBtnHome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="14dip"
        android:src="@drawable/home" 
        android:background="@drawable/black"/>
    <TextView 
        android:text="Home" 
        android:textSize="8dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footerLayoutProducts"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/footerMainBtnProducts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="14dip"
            android:src="@drawable/products" 
            android:background="@drawable/black"/> 
        <TextView 
            android:text="Products" 
            android:textSize="8dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footerLayoutCart"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/footerMainBtnCart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="14dip"
            android:src="@drawable/cart" 
            android:background="@drawable/black"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="Cart" 
            android:textSize="8dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/footerLayoutFeedback"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/footerMainBtnFeedback"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="14dip"
        android:src="@drawable/feedback" 
        android:background="@drawable/black"/>
        <TextView 
        android:text="Feedback" 
        android:textSize="8dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>  

   <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/footerLayoutHelp"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/footerMainBtnHelp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="14dip" 
        android:src="@drawable/help" 
        android:background="@drawable/black"/>
       <TextView 
        android:text="Help" 
        android:textSize="8dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>                
  </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browserwebview);
    searchEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchCatalogButton);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String urlSearchKey = searchEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if(urlSearchKey==""){
                Toast.makeText(Catalog.this, "Enter Search Keyword", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else{
                url=urlforthesite+urlSearchKey;
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                searchEditText.setText("");
            }

        }
    });`
```

Looking forward to your reply.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey..can you post Some code..that will increase SO Supporter's interest to Go through the Problem in your Code.

Comment: @HareshChaudhary I have attached the code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of textbox in webview may differ from device to device,
according to customization of webkit.
In original android source code textBox is combined with editText of android view.
But in device it can give a different look.
So this is not a problem its just a behavior of that api.
Check it on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Do this **2 things**.Might Solve Your Problem: :))

**1)** Add  `android:focusable="true"` in webView

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/browserwebview"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"  
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
  />
```

**2)** Add `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`; in Your Java Code